# throw new Error или throw error в nestjs. Стоит ли вести спор с тим лидом?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Нам необходимо отправлять апи запросы в сторонний сервис через библиотеку graphql-request, которая внутри выполняет запрос используя axios. При обработке ошибок у нас с лидом образовался спор как лучше это реализовать. Лид настаивает на том, что throw new Error является необходим по следующим причинам

1. "без throw new Error не будет стека"
2. "Это глобальный подход, нивелирующий ошибки в будущем"
3. "Писать new Error надо как защиту от да***ов. Писать нужно так, будто все вокруг да***бы и тебе надо от них защищаться"
4. "Ошибка из акисоса всегда будет возвращаться как экземпляр Error, но в либе на 50млн загрузок тоже может быть ошибка"

**Пример финального результата от лида:**

```
корневой gql запрос

api/api.service.ts

async request(document, variables) {
    try {
        const response = await this.gqlClient.request(document, variables)

        return {
            data: response,
            error: undefined,
        }
    } catch (error) {
         // ...логика повторного запроса при неудаче

       if(error.response){
          return {
                data: undefined,
                error: {
                    code: error.response.status,
                    message: error.response.message,
                },
            }
       }
          
       
        throw new Error(error)
    }
}
```

кастомная ошибка

```
const errorMessages = {
UNAUTHORIZED: 'Ошибка авторизации',
CAT_NOT_FOUND: 'Кот не найден'
//...остальные ошибки
}

class CastomError extends Error {
    constructor(name, message) {
        super(message || errorMessages[name])
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

каждый отдельный запрос апи использует общий requst и общий обработчик ошибок handleCommonError

```
async getCat(variables) {
    const { data, error } = await this.request(mutaion, variables)

    if (error) {
        if (error.code === 404) {
            throw new CastomError('CAT_NOT_FOUND')
        }

        throw this.handleCommonError(error)
    }

    return data
}


handleCommonError(error) {
    if (error.code === 401) {
        throw new DvizhError(DvizhErrorName.UNAUTHORIZED)
    }
    
    //...

    throw new Error(error)
}
```

использование методов апи в сервисе контролера.

resourse/resourse.service.ts

```
async getCat(body) {
    try {
        await this.apiService.createCat(body)
    } catch (error) {
        throw handleApiError(error)
    }

    //... какой-то запрос в базу

    let cat
    try {
        cat = await this.apiService.getCate(body)
    } catch (error) {
        throw handleApiError(error)
    }
    

    return cat
}

const handleApiError = (error) => {
   if (error instanceof CastomError) {
    switch (error.name) {
        case errorMessages.CAT_NOT_FOUND:
            throw new NotFoundException(error.message)

        case errorMessages.UNAUTHORIZED:
            throw new UnauthorizedException(error.message)
    }
  }

  throw new Error(error)
}
```

Из-за того что требуется возвращать в handleApiError ошибку обязательно как new Error. На каждый метод приходится дублировать try catсh. Хендлер нельзя использовать глобально для метода, т.к. тогда в handleApiError нужно будет дополнительно проверять ещё и на HttpExeption. Лид считает, что это наоборот дает возможность не оборачивать весь метод в try catch и лучше обработать каждый запрос по отдельности. Для чего возвращается new Error в handleApiError, если из методов апи обработчик handleCommonError возвращает уже всегда new Error?

Лично мне этот подход не нравится. throw new Error только все усложняет. Axios всегда должен возвращать ошибку со стеком. И мы не сможем как-то обезопасить себя от битого кода. Если код пройдет ревью в таком случае можно будет сделать не только throw 'string', но и к примеру убрать где-то авторизацию, валидаторы, да и в принципе сделать что угодно

Как вы считаете есть ли здесь на самом деле необходимость в new Error. И хорошее ли решение возвращать { data, error } из метода request и проверять общие ошибки в каждом методе по-отдельности, вместо того чтобы оформить один глобальный обработчик на все методы внутри request

После данного кейса было решено использовать throw new Error() везде. Какие по-настоящему есть оправданные случае в несте, где нужно использовать throw new Error(error) вместо throw error? И как вы считаете стоит ли в целом вести спор до талого, чтобы довести свою точку зрения когда идея не принимается, либо же проще работать по принципу "работа 8часов, что поручено то и делается"?

Answer (score 0):

1. существуют фильтры в Nest, которые позволяют обрабатывать ошибки и не приходится писать обработку в каждом роуте.
2. библиотека должна выбрасывать исключение `CatsServiceNotFound` и не привязываться к сущьности, ну или првязываться только сообщением. Если у вас нет прям спицифичной логики под такое решение.
3. Есть такой функционал как `instanceof` и как раз в глобальном фильтре можно проверить `if (exception instanceof CatsServiceNotFound) { throw new NotFoundException(error.message) }` или вообще наследовать `CatsServiceNotFound` от `NotFoundException`, что позволит не мапить ошибки в дальнейшем коде. Делать мапинг ошибок по их имени так себе затея, хоть они и enum у вас.

Также в этом коде непонятно зачем каждый кусок кода оборачивать в свой `try`, полчается много лишних обработок. Ведь `throw error` останавливает выполнение дальнейшего когда.

P.S. моё лично мнение о вашем подходе...